# SQL statement help : select products tradable till specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

Say I have a table which stores order IDs and the corresponding products - like this:

```
Product ID | Order ID (PK) | Order Placement Date
Apple      | 2455          | 2022-04-18 13:55:50.100
Apple      | 2456          | 2022-04-18 15:50:40.100
Appel      | 3457          | 2022-04-18 17:59:10.100
Appel      | 3458          | 2022-04-18 18:40:10.100
Appel      | 3459          | 2022-04-19 09:30:50.100
Appel      | 3459          | 2022-04-19 14:20:20.100
```

How can I get on a daily basis all the products that are tradable ( Orders placed ) at any point from 18:00 CET yesterday and before 18:00 CET that day. So new products tradable after 18:00 CET on that day, placed for the first time, must be included in the next day select data ?

Also `Order Placement Date` would be a `DateTime` - UTC timezoned and I'm working with SQL Server 2019.

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product ID, Order ID, Order Placement Date
FROM TableName
Where Order Placement Date --> From yesterday 18h until today 18:00 CET
```

Select result sample when in 2022-04-18 :

```
Product ID | Order ID (PK) | Order Placement Date
Apple      | 2455          | 2022-04-18 13:55:50.100
Apple      | 2456          | 2022-04-18 15:50:40.100
Appel      | 3457          | 2022-04-18 17:59:10.100
```

Select result sample when in 2022-04-19 :

```
Product ID | Order ID (PK) | Order Placement Date
Appel      | 3458          | 2022-04-18 18:40:10.100
Appel      | 3459          | 2022-04-19 09:30:50.100
Appel      | 3459          | 2022-04-19 14:20:20.100
```

Comment: Could you provide some smaple data and expect result?

Comment: What data type is `Order Placement Date`? Is it timezone aware? if not, how do you know what time zone a value in the row is?

Comment: Could you not just check against the time and day and do a greater than check?

Comment: Do you also *always* want CET (UTC+1)? At the moment Central Europe is observing CEST, which is UTC+2.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your remarks. CET time is now UTC+2 (=CEST). Is there a way to adapt it the timezone change (CET/CEST) ?

Comment: `I'm working with SQL Server` but you left out `_ _ _ _`. 2000? 2008? 2019? `AT TIME ZONE` might be an option but if all of the data is already in CET I'm not sure you need to do any conversion at all. Again, table structure, sample data (including edge cases), and desired results would make your issue a lot easier to solve than a word problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I added details, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little messy, but should work. I suspect there might be a less ugly method but oh well. I do, however, assume you are using a recent version of SQL Server, which supports `AT TIME ZONE`.

First we get the current date; I am **assuming** that "today" is from the server's perspective. Then we `CONVERT` to a `date` (to remove the time) and then back to a `datetime2`, so we can use `AT TIME ZONE`, which we state to be Central Europe. SQL Server which automatically process for DST and it'll assume the `datetime2` value was correct for the timezone. Then we change that time to UTC and `CONVERT` back to a `datetime` so that there is no implicit conversions on the column. Then we do the same for the upper boundary, but with 8 hours added on:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ProductID int,
                            OrderID int,
                            OrderPlacementDate datetime); --Per question, this is UTC

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ProductID,
                           OrderID,
                           OrderPlacementDate)
VALUES(2,2,'20220418 21:48:59.123'), --Would be 2022-04-18 23:48:59.123 CEST
      (1,1,'20220418 22:15:17.167'), --Would be 2022-04-19 00:15:17.167 CEST
      (1,1,'20220419 15:15:17.167'), --Would be 2022-04-19 17:15:17.167 CEST
      (1,1,'20220419 16:15:17.167'); --Would be 2022-04-19 18:15:17.167 CEST
GO


SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE OrderPlacementDate >= CONVERT(datetime,(CONVERT(datetime2(3),CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
  AND OrderPlacementDate <= CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(datetime2(3),CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a2fd41ae340287af9809fec75ccdad6)

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution @Larnu but while giving it a detailed look, `20220418 21:48:59.123` should also be included in the result table. The idea was to include data from 18h CET yesterday to 18h CET today

Comment: That isn't what you stated in the question I answered, @selmase, which states "Today until 18:00 CET" You'll need to amend the above to fit your new needs (which shouldn't be hard, as you already have the logic for the upper boundary).

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I thought it was clear initially for the requirement. I've edited my post so it can be more clear now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE [Order Placement Date] < DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),DAY(GETDATE()),18,0,0,0)
AND [Order Placement Date] >= DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())),MONTH(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())),DAY(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())),18,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Where does this take into account that the time range being queried is based on CET/CEST while the data stored is UTC?